# Book suggestions for Combinatorics for IMO

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, book-recommendation

I'm currently preparing Combinatorics for IMO (International Mathematical Olympiad). I searched through the web (including some threads in MSE), for the best book recommendations. After a lot of "research", I decided to go with $$ Problem-Solving \  Methods \  in  \ Combinatorics \ by  \ Pablo \ Soberon. $$

Some other books I went through were either very difficult for me, or way too easy.

I started with the book, then I find it really difficult to understand the examples illustrated in it. It's not that I am a beginner in combinatorics, but I don't know why I was finding it very difficult.

I am just not able to get a proper book since a couple of days.
And the only way for me to study is through a good book.

Can anyone suggest me the best books for combinatorics, highly relevant for Mathematical Olympiads? I will be very helpful.

I hope I have cleared things properly.

I know that a lot of people have asked the same question here already, but many of them were for Research related, and for just problem solving.

Thanks.

EDIT: AFTER A LOT OF CONSIDERATIONS, I HAVE DECIDED TO GO WITH THE BOOK $$ A \ Path \ to \ Combinatorics \ for \ Undergraduates \ $$ by $ Titu \ Andreescu. $

I just wanted to ask if this book is Olympiad oriented, or Olympiad relevant, as it's title doesn't seem to suggest that?

Comment: This unfinished book is pretty good imho https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h601134

Comment: @Yorch thanks for your comment, but I have already gone through that book, and found it very difficult, it's tougher than IMO, till china level.

Comment: Have you already gone through “102 Combinatorial Problems: From the Training of the USA IMO Team” by Titu Andreescu and Zuming Feng containing 51 introductory problems' and 51 advanced problems ?

Answer (score 2):

- Introduction to Combinatorics - Gerry Leversha and Dominic Rowland
- Topics in Combinatorics - Gerry Leversha and Dominic Rowland

They are aimed at national maths contestants.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do you know if I can get a free pdf copy of the books you mentioned? I searched it on the internet, but couldn't find.

Comment: Amazon or https://www.ukmt.org.uk/shop . They're very fairly priced compared to many other texts.